# Grails and redirect with spring security core

Tags: grails, redirect, spring-security

I am trying to implement a login system such that the user is redirected back to the original request url. For example, if a user tries to access url '/books/list' (which requires login to access) then the user should be redirect to login page and after login, the user should be redirected to '/books/list', the original requested url. How do I do this ?
My login controller looks like :

```
def index = {
if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
    redirect action: 'dashboard'
    //redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.login.filterProcessesUrl
}
else {

  redirect action: auth, params: params
}
}


def auth = {


def config = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig

if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
  redirect uri: config.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
  return
}

String view = 'auth'
String postUrl = "${request.contextPath}${config.apf.filterProcessesUrl}"
render view: view, model: [postUrl: postUrl,
        rememberMeParameter: config.rememberMe.parameter]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Spring Security Core plugin does this by default.

Comment: Right, this is core Spring Security functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting to the requested url after sign in , you just need to add the following in your config.groovy file.

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl = false
grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "InterceptUrlMap"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [   
'/**': ["IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"]
]
```

Comment: I think we need to add one line
`grails.plugins.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl = false` into `Config.groovy`